# How to differentiate between buttons using the same class using a function?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, eventhandler

I have this simple page set up which will add or remove a hidden class on an element when either button is clicked. The code works fine as is, but I know that it's very inefficient. I plan on adding more buttons and don't want to make a new function and event listener for each one. Rather than having a separate function for each button I would like to make 1 function which can differentiate which button was pressed and add the hidden class based on that. Any ideas?

```
 <style>
    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <header>
      <button class="nav-link link-home">Home</button>
      <button class="nav-link link-about">About</button>
    </header>
    <main>
      <h1 class="main-content home-page hidden">This is the Home Page</h1>
      <h1 class="main-content about-page hidden">This is the About Page</h1>
    </main>
    <script>
      const navLink = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');
      const linkHome = document.querySelector('.link-home');
      const linkAbout = document.querySelector('.link-about');
      const mainContent = document.querySelectorAll('.main-content');
      const homePage = document.querySelector('.home-page');
      const aboutPage = document.querySelector('.about-page');

      const openHome = () => {
        homePage.classList.remove('hidden');
        aboutPage.classList.add('hidden');
      };
      linkHome.addEventListener('click', openHome);

      const openAbout = () => {
        aboutPage.classList.remove('hidden');
        homePage.classList.add('hidden');
      };
      linkAbout.addEventListener('click', openAbout);
    </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data` attribute to link each `link` with its corresponding page, and add event listner for all `links` that have the `data-link` attribute and on `click` get the value of `data-link` and `querySelector` the `data-page` with this value, then `add` hidden class to all links and `remove` hidden class from the target page.

```html
<style>
    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <header>
      <button class="nav-link link-home" data-link="home">Home</button>
      <button class="nav-link link-about" data-link="about">About</button>
    </header>
    <main>
      <h1 class="main-content home-page" data-page="home">This is the Home Page</h1>
      <h1 class="main-content about-page hidden" data-page="about">This is the About Page</h1>
    </main>
    <script>
      const links = document.querySelectorAll('[data-link]');
      const pages = document.querySelectorAll('[data-page]');
      links.forEach(link => {
           link.addEventListener('click', () => {
             pages.forEach(page => page.classList.add('hidden'));
             const page = document.querySelector(`[data-page="${link.dataset.link}"]`);
             page.classList.remove('hidden');
         })
      })

    </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
const open = (className) => {
    const page = document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0];
    page.classList.remove('hidden');
    page.classList.add('hidden');
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a generic event handler which - when called - makes all `.main-content` hidden and then unhides the relevant `.main-content` based on (for example) the button text:

```js
const navLink = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');
const mainContent = document.querySelectorAll('.main-content');

navLink.forEach(l => l.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // hide all divs
  mainContent.forEach(c => c.classList.add('hidden'))
  // show the one of interest
  content = `.${e.target.textContent.toLowerCase()}-page`
  document.querySelector(content).classList.remove('hidden')
}))
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <button class="nav-link link-home">Home</button>
    <button class="nav-link link-about">About</button>
  </header>
  <main>
    <h1 class="main-content home-page hidden">This is the Home Page</h1>
    <h1 class="main-content about-page hidden">This is the About Page</h1>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do what you want. One of them would work like this:

```js
// Get all elements with class nav-link
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');

// Loop through each nav-link element
navLinks.forEach(function(navlink){
  // Add click event listener to each nav-link element
  navlink.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    // Make sure the button being clicked exists
    if(e.target){
      // Get all classes on the element
      const classes = e.target.classList;
      
      // Loop through the classList to identify the buttons
      classes.forEach(function(btnClass){
        // Try to split the class at -
        const classNameArray = btnClass.split('-');
        
        // Make sure at least 2 array keys exist
        if(1 in classNameArray){
            // Make sure the class started with 'link'
          if(classNameArray[0] === 'link'){
            // Target the correct element to add the class
            const page = document.querySelector('.'+classNameArray[1]+'-page');
            
            // Add hidden class to all pages
            document.querySelectorAll('.main-content').forEach(function(element){
              if(!element.classList.contains('hidden')){
                element.classList.add('hidden');
              }
            });
            
            // Remove hidden class from the page
            if(page.classList.contains('hidden')){
                page.classList.remove('hidden');
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <button class="nav-link link-home">Home</button>
  <button class="nav-link link-about">About</button>
</header>
<main>
  <h1 class="main-content home-page hidden">This is the Home Page</h1>
  <h1 class="main-content about-page hidden">This is the About Page</h1>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use '[Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)' to select different elements in page just by one click and know which element is selected then one function need:

```
<style>
    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }
</style>

  <body>
    <header>
      <button id="btn-home" class="nav-link link-home">Home</button>
      <button id="btn-about" class="nav-link link-about">About</button>
    </header>
    <main>
      <h1 class="main-content home-page hidden">This is the Home Page</h1>
      <h1 class="main-content about-page hidden">This is the About Page</h1>
    </main>
    <script>
      const navLink = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');
      const linkHome = document.querySelector('.link-home');
      const linkAbout = document.querySelector('.link-about');
      const mainContent = document.querySelectorAll('.main-content');
      const homePage = document.querySelector('.home-page');
      const aboutPage = document.querySelector('.about-page');

      
      function handler (event) {

        if (event.target.textContent === 'Home') {
            homePage.classList.remove('hidden');
            aboutPage.classList.add('hidden');
        }else if (event.target.textContent === 'About') {
            aboutPage.classList.remove('hidden');
            homePage.classList.add('hidden');
        }
      }

      document.body.addEventListener('click', handler);

    </script>
  </body>
```